# iastora.sys failed (windows 10 bluescreen error)

Tags: windows-10

I have received this error for about the third time in the last couple of days. I don't know what it is or how to fix it. It happens after turning the system on again from sleep mode and sometimes from turning it off after a soft shutdown. I noticed that chrome resets my tabs as well. Luckily I can use the "Restore" button when this happens. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iastora.sys is a Driver for the Intel Storage Array.  My suggestion would be to run Windows Update to check for any updates to Windows and to check Intel's website for any driver updates.  Intel has a nice Driver Support Assistant to assist in finding driver updates: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html